# How to get Bounding rectangle using Remote ObjectId using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, python, automation, google-chrome-devtools, playwright

The `DOM snapshot` is taken by the below code in `Playwright Python`.

```
tree = client.send("DOMSnapshot.captureSnapshot", {
        "computedStyles": [],
        "includeDOMRects": True,
        "includePaintOrder": True,
        "includeScrollRects": True,
        "includeStackTraces": True
    })
```

After scanning through it, a single element is identified to be clicked. It has `backendNodeId` as a node identifier.

It is brought into `viewport` using,

```
id= element["backendNodeId"]
client.send("DOM.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded", {"backendNodeId": int(id)})
```

If the element was hidden under the `scroll` and it will be brought into the viewport.

This leads to a change the in `bounding rectangle` of the element than what was captured previous DOM Snapshot.

To get the latest values, if snapshot is taken again, the `backendNodeId` for each element changes.

Hence tried to make a click or fetch bounding rectangle using `Runtime.callFunctionOn` but it's not working as it is not able to create node reference.

```
result = client.send("DOM.resolveNode", {"backendNodeId": int(id)})

objectId = result["object"]["objectId"]
result5 = client.send("Runtime.callFunctionOn", {
     "objectId": objectId,
     "functionDeclaration": 'function(this) { 
     this.click();
     return this.getBoundingClientRect();
     }'})
```

1. Is there anything missing in `functionDeclaration` logic?
2. Is there a way to trigger a `click event` or to get the `bounding rectangle` of any element having its `backendNodeId` or `remoteObjectId`?

Note: `No typical attributes of the element will be reliable` as it needs to run across multiple applications with varying attribute sets.

Eg. id, name are not available always.

Please comment if more information is required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: 1) Maybe the site replaces the element with a new one after scrolling, so try finding it via CSS/xpath selector again. 2) The result of getBoundingClientRect is not serializable directly so you should explicitly return the individual properties that you need.

Comment: 1) Yes, found after debugging that after scrolling some elements are removed and some are added dynamically. Not sure if Xpath will remain the same but am gonna give it a try. 2) Current logic is not any response as it's not able to resolve this/element probably.

Comment: Verified that due to dynamic elements, the XPath is returning different elements after the scroll. Hence Xpath is not reliable here.